# Notice: Undefined index: file in php

Tags: php, file, upload

please, i have a probleme in uploading images
In fact, there is my code :
-this is my html form :

```
            <div class="galery-upload">
                    <form action="include/galery-upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          <input type="file" name="filename">

                           <button type="submit" name="galery-upload-submit">UPLOAD</button>

                    </form>

                </div>
```

-this is php code :

```
 <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imguploads");
session_start();
$useruid =  $_SESSION['useruid'];
if (isset($_POST['galery-upload-submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    if (empty($file)) {
        echo "no exist file";
    }
    else {


    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileExt = explode('.',$filename);
    $fileActualExt = end($fileExt);
    $fileNameNew = "galery".".".uniqid($useruid, true).".".$fileActualExt ;
    $folder = "C:/xampp2/htdocs/miniprojet/galery/".$fileNameNew;
    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $folder);
    }}
    ?>
```

and get this error : 
Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp2\htdocs\miniprojet\include\galery-upload.inc.php on line 6
no exist file

Any solutions please !!!!!

Comment: $_FILES['file'] is not set. What does var_dump($_FILES) say?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your input name is `filename` so:

```
$file = $_FILES['filename'];
```

Comment: thank you my friends it is work

Comment: did you down vote my answer? if it was helpful please up vote my answer